# Outcome doesn't make sense for list of most common POS

Tags: python, nltk

I'm trying to get a list of the most frequent POS tags from a collection of posts.
I have written the following:

```
    text2=corpus
    text4=nltk.word_tokenize(text2)
    tags=nltk.pos_tag(text4)
    for a,b in tags:
        counter2={}
        l=wordpunct_tokenize(b) 

    for i in l: counter2[i] = counter2.get (i,0)+1
        list5=sorted([(freq,word) for word, freq in counter.items()], reverse=True)[:3]
        print list5
```

The supposed outcome would be for instance

```
NN, JJ, PRP...
```

however I get this nonsense:

```
[(539, ','), (476, '.'), (385, '?')]
```

with not a single grammatical tag in it.

While b looks like:

```
CC
WP
PRP
VBD
NNP
NNP
PRP
VBD
VBG
TO
VB
PRP$
NN
```

does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the indentation in your post is messed up, but here's what I think you are trying to do (print the top 3 parts of speech):

```
text2=corpus
text4=nltk.word_tokenize(text2)
tags=nltk.pos_tag(text4)
counter2={}
for a,b in tags:
    counter2[b] = counter2.get(b,0)+1
list5=sorted([(freq,word) for word, freq in counter2.items()], reverse=True)[:3]
print [word for freq,word in list5]
```

I don't think you want to tokenize "b".